# How to execute a system command from a python file

Tags: python, operating-system, command, execute

I am using python and trying to execute a system command as below

**code.py**

```
import commands
import os

os.system('updatedb')
```

**result:**

```
sh-4.2$ python code.py
updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'
```

So how to execute all the system commands like above from a python module ?

Comment: The error indicates that you do not have permissions to run the **updatedb** command.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that it was called from Python. Have you tried running `updatedb` in the command line? You'll almost certainly get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a permissions problem?

Comment: yes actually when i tried it in terminal without entering in to root... its displaying the same error, but when i tried from root executed successfully.... so finally there is no way to get the rsult from python by getting in to root or making this executable ?

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly simply a permissions problem.
If you can trust your script to run as root:

```
$ sudo python code.py
```

Comment: Just because i usually run it in linux server to update db and perform some additional operations with help of cron jobs. so in server that too with cron jobs it is not possible to provide a password to run the script

Comment: @Fedrik: In that case, it sounds like the issue is getting that cron job to run as root.